# Get data from CSV file and add it to an array, then encrypt

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes, file-io

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '$file'
INTO TABLE table
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(number, type)
```

if i can't just encrypt  the data directly in the query, is it possible to get all the results and add them to an array, and then encrypt them one by one and insert them into the database?

Answer (score -1):

Another way:

Create new CSV file (using original CSV file) with encrypted content then use the same LOAD DATA INFILE query for importing content at once.

It will save one by one insertion.

Correct me if i'm wrong.